# Receptacle tester shows "correct" although ground is disconnected

Tags: wiring, receptacle, gfci, grounding

If I disconnect the "ground" wire at the junction box that feeds a GFCI outlet/receptacle, I was expecting a receptacle tester to show "open ground", instead it says "correct". Could something weird be going on with the wiring or is my understanding incorrect?

Comment: Is your box metal or plastic? Are your wires in cables or conduit? What model of tester?

Comment: Is the yoke touching the box, if the ground was connected to the box the box is ground and if the metal yoke is touching the box it will be grounded or through through the screws. Why are you disconnecting grounds?

Comment: Further to above comment, if for some reason you are just wanting to see how your tester reacts to this scenario of GFCI without ground, remove the receptacle from the box, leaving it dangling by just the live and netural wires and not touching anything else in any way.  Perhaps that will help you to observe or prove what you are attempting.  Make sure nobody else will fiddle with it while you run back to the panel to turn it on and run back to see what the tester says.

Answer (score 1):

An ungrounded GFCI “Is Acceptable”. A GFCI does not need a ground wire in order to trip properly. A GFCI simply trips when a fault is detected on the neutral wire.

Also, GFCI's can be used in place of ungrounded receptacles AND used for those ungrounded receptacles down line on the same branch circuit. All receptacles must be labeled GFCI protected AND Ungrounded Equipment in such cases

Comment: Just to clarify "acceptable".  It is acceptable for renovation of old wiring where running ground wire would mean tearing open existing walls.  New construction is required to be grounded, GFCI or not.  That's my understanding any way.  Grounding by metal conduit, as opposed to separate copper wire, is acceptable for new construction, no?  Yes?

Comment: @MacGuffin in regards to renovation goes, always refer to your local codes and for clarity speak to your local building division or inspector. Now in regards to acceptable, it is in regards to your actual post with concerns of no ground wire and no error being produced. Because a ground wire is not needed in order for the GFCI to work properly and trip when a fault is detected.

Comment: While I understand that some specifics will be up to local codes there must be something in the NEC, and even in foreign codes, on what is "acceptable" when it comes to a ground wire.  Isn't there a "rule of thumb" that is widely accepted?  Even if debated where some exceptions apply?  I'm pretty sure ungrounded outlets are a no-go universally in any building codes on new construction, GFCI or not.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Might help for someone else in the future. Acceptable means not lacking ground. So if it is grounded by the GFCI or actual ground wire then it meets code. Only when no type of ground is present one must label it as ungrounded. Which I wrote in the original answer.

Answer (score 0):

I did not see an answer to my comment , but many homes use metal boxes and for stucco or metal sided homes and homes using metal flex or conduit the ground can come from the “yoke or strap” that connects the recepto the metal box.

It is code compliant to have an ungrounded 3 pin socket in the US as long as it is GFCI protected. By code the face plate is required to have a sticker stating GFCI protected, no equipment ground. And these come with the receptacle type GFCI’s. Not usually with the breakers or the brands I use don’t have the stickers just the receptacles.